# When creating a user component I want to have Db Column in the schema

Tags: etl, talend

I've tried to create a usercomponent for talend which will act like an input. I have very strange column names in the database export (coming from SAP R3 / ECC) I'm trying to read, however I've created an additional component which can create schema xml-s. These xml-s contain the dBcolumn as well as the column I'd like to use as the output from component.

I can generate these xml-s for different languages, so I can use english/german/italian names 10,20 or 50 character long for the columns instead of their 5-10 character abbreviation.

My problem is that I'm not able to see the Db Column in my user components schema. I didn't find anything related to this. I have my components located under "Business/SAP".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the xml like this:

[image: Family: Databases/SAP]

After that I'm able to see the Db Columns:

[image: Db Column]